# Product names not updating in Magento 2.1.0

Tags: cache, reindex, magento2.1.0, name

```
Porto theme
```

We have 2 stores (I just added a new one). In the new store - I initially put in 5 products:

The first one with the correct product name but the other 4 with:

```
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 4
```

as the names of the products.

I later changed those, deleted all the Cache and successfully re-indexed the main store/domain with SSH (Putty):

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**But the products still show the old Product names (Product 1, 2, 3, and 4) INSTEAD of what it actually shows in:**

*Products --) Catalog --)  Product Name*